# looping through dataset once at test time in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

What's the best way to take a single pass over a dataset, in order to evaluate on test data?  I'd like to avoid scripting the data loading in python and using a `feed_dict`. Instead, I'd like to use all the nice TF infrastructure for queueing, batching, etc.

In the cifar [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.7/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py#L92), the number of test examples is hard-coded and the code takes `num_test_examples/batch_size` steps in order to do evaluation. It seems like there should be a better way to do this, using the batching infrastructure.

It seems that the standard pattern is to stop running when you catch some exception thrown by the queue. I've tried some things, such that the queue complains when there are no more examples to populate the queue (ie the Producer can't produce any more). This isn't the exception you want to catch. You want to catch when the consumer has nothing left to consume, ie the queue is empty. How do I do this?

Also, what do you do if the number of test examples isn't divisible by a batch size (eg. the number of test examples is prime).

Additional information:

In practice, we typically evaluate on test data multiple times during learning, by calling a `do_evaluation()` function. Yaroslav's answer is useful if you only want process the test data once. Ideally, each call to do_evaluation would run over every example in the test dataset exactly once. We need some mechanism for resetting the batcher so that you can take a single pass over it one more time. Here's some code for that. Don't use the `limit_epochs` command. It takes a batcher that doesn't shuffle and specify the number of batches in the test set (this doesn't work if the number of examples set isn't divisible by minibatchsize). The function returns a new op for grabbing data that will throw a `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` when you've run over the whole set. The second return value is an op that should be called to reset the counter. This should be the first call inside a `do_evaluation()` function.

```py
def single_pass(source_batcher,num_batches):
    zero = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int64)
    batch_count = tf.Variable(zero, name="epochs", trainable=False)
    limiter = tf.count_up_to(batch_count,num_batches)
    with tf.control_dependencies([limiter]):
      batcher = tf.identity(source_batcher)

    reset = tf.assign(batch_count, zero)

    return batcher, reset
```

Comment: Use `num_epochs` in your input producer and catch `OutOfRange` exception.

Comment: Thanks. This works overall. Just to clarify: num_epochs should be added to tf.train.string_input_producer; don't use tf.limit_epoch. What do I do when the number of examples isn't divisible by the minibatchsize? Right now, I have 1500 examples and batchsize=32. The code generates 47 batches, for a total of 1504 examples. What's the correct pattern for processing exactly 1500 examples?

Comment: Ideally your network doesn't have batch size baked into it, so that you can feed arbitrary number of examples per batch

Comment: I encountered the same problem, i.e. the the number of examples set isn't divisible by minibatchsize. However I still cannot figure out your solution. Do you have a more detailed code snippet for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tf.Data API for this. Like so.

```
import tensorflow as tf

graph = tf.Graph()
sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)


def build_dataset(train_or_test):
    if train_or_test == 'test':
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.zeros([4, 2]))
    elif train_or_test == 'train':
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.ones([10, 2]))
    else:
        raise ValueError('wrong name')
    batch_size = 3
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset


def build_inputs():
    train_dataset = build_dataset('train')
    test_dataset = build_dataset('test')
    iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(
        train_dataset.output_types,
        train_dataset.output_shapes,)
    data = iterator.get_next()
    tf.identity(data, name='data')
    iterator.make_initializer(train_dataset, name='train_init')
    iterator.make_initializer(test_dataset, name='test_init')


def model(inputs):
    return tf.add(inputs, 1, name='output')


def build_graph():
    with graph.as_default():
        build_inputs()
        data = graph.get_tensor_by_name('data:0')
        model(data)


def train():
    train_init = graph.get_operation_by_name('train_init')
    sess.run(train_init)
    out = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output:0')
    while True:
        try:
            network_out = sess.run(out)
            print(network_out.shape)
            print(network_out)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break


def test():
    test_init = graph.get_operation_by_name('test_init')
    sess.run(test_init)
    out = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output:0')
    while True:
        try:
            network_out = sess.run(out)
            print(network_out.shape)
            print(network_out)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break


def train_loop():
    cur_epoch = 0
    while cur_epoch < 1:
        print('Test epoch')
        test()
        print('Train epoch')
        train()
        cur_epoch += 1


def initialise_graph():
    with graph.as_default():
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


build_graph()
initialise_graph()
train_loop()
```

This will output:

```
Test epoch
(3, 2)
[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]]
(1, 2)
[[1. 1.]]
Train epoch
(3, 2)
[[2. 2.]
 [2. 2.]
 [2. 2.]]
(3, 2)
[[2. 2.]
 [2. 2.]
 [2. 2.]]
(3, 2)
[[2. 2.]
 [2. 2.]
 [2. 2.]]
(1, 2)
[[2. 2.]]
```